# Passing a param as a query string or part of url?

Tags: laravel

Should you pass a param to a GET request as part of the URL or as a query string, for example?

`Route::get('/image/{id}', 'ImageController@get');`

Should we do:

1. `/image/10`
2. `/image?id=10`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question of which approach **should** you do is one I won't answer, as that's entirely up to you to determine which method you'd want to do.

With your current Route, only one of the supplied URLs would hit the `get()` method in your `ImageController`.

`/image/10` matches your Route, and would be used as:

```
public function get($id){ 
  dd($id); // 10
}
```

`/image?id=10` doesn't match your URL, and would be a 404 due to a missing parameter. The route would need to be modified to:

```
Route::get('/image', 'ImageController@get');
```

And your Controller method would need to be:

```
public function get(Request $request){ 
  $id = $request->input('id');
  dd($id); // 10
}
```

There's pros and cons to each approach, Query String params are good for multiple required and/or option parameters, while URL params are better suited to single required/optional. Multiple optional URL params is not something that is supported, so keep that in mind.

Comment: Thank you for a well crafted answer.